# Почему причастие обозначает признак по действию, а не наоборот?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, причастия

Причастие это форма глагола, которая обозначает **признак по действию**.

Это известное определение причастия.

Но почему нельзя  сказать так: **причастие обозначает  действие как признак,** поставив действие на первое место, это же всё-таки  форма **глагола**.

**Почему у меня возник такой странный вопрос?** В Сети мне встретилось мнение, что именно причастие обозначает постоянный качественный признак?

Вы удивлены, откуда такое странное понимание?  **А объяснение там приводилось такое**. Качественный признак создается в результате завершения  действия,  а это как раз значение  страдательного причастия прошедшего времени. Действие закончилось, вот и появился постоянный (уже не меняющийся) признак.

А вот при другой формулировке (причастие обозначает действие как признак) такое  понимание было бы вряд ли возможно. **Причастие – это как бы тоже глагол**,  имеющий особую грамматическую форму, совпадающую с грамматической формой  прилагательного.

Я привожу частный случай, может, и не стоящий особого внимания, но есть и **общая проблема**, а именно сложность различения причастий и прилагательных. Вот мне и думается, что иное определение могло бы способствовать лучшему усвоению темы.

Тогда бы это понималось так: **если нет действия, в том числе завершенного, значит, нет и причастия.**

Примечание

А что бы я ответила этому пользователю, у которого причастие обозначает постоянный качественный признак? Наверное, так: "Извини, друг, но ты один так думаешь". С другой стороны, он  думает, хотя и неправильно, а мы просто заучили данное нам определение. Причем давно, еще в школе, а после ни разу не усомнились в его правильности.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 26.05.2020**

1) Судя по отсутствию ответов, я полагаю, что вопрос  показался участникам форума **праздным, умозрительным и не имеющим практического интереса** (а может быть, и никакого интереса вообще). Поэтому я не прошу вас  на него ответить, как просила до этого, но всё-таки надеюсь на внимание со стороны других пользователей Сети.

2) Возможно, формулировка определения сложилась **исторически** (а это тоже очень любопытно), но тогда насколько она **соответствует** современному пониманию проблемы?

Мы мало обращаемся **к истории терминологии**, как будто  она вообще не имеет истории, это нам тоже неинтересно.  Скорее всего, в школах нет таких факультативных курсов, и мы **привыкли пользоваться готовыми знаниями**.  А ведь история  практической лингвистики – это  хороший способ развития мышления для людей любых профессий, а не только филологов.

3) Что касается меня, то я вижу в своем вопросе **чисто практический интерес.** Пользователи  затрудняются с различением причастий и прилагательных, так как отсутствуют **четкие определения** того и другого. А любой научный подход, как всем известно, начинается именно с постулатов/аксиом и определений.

4) Можно, конечно, сказать: это такая **сложная и неоднозначная** тема, неудивительно, что в ней трудно разобраться.

**А мир вообще сложен**, и любое явление в нем мы описываем, используя определенные **модели** (при этом выделяем главное, отвлекаемся от несущественного).

И если создается такая модель, то она должна быть **непротиворечивой**. В противном же случае следует от нее отказаться, создать новую модель или внести изменения в существующую.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 28.05.2020**

1) Это я так думаю (ответ **на комментарий С.**):

Признак – это ЗНАК, по которому мы классифицируем (определяем) предмет, иначе говоря, выбираем его среди других подобных предметов. Это может быть качество или действие.

Признаком  (знаком) причастия является **действие**. Можно сказать: причастие **обозначает действие** как признак предмета, а прилагательное (кач.) обозначает **качество** как признак предмета.

Надо отметить, что причастие заимствует у прилагательного не только форму (какой), но и синтаксическую функцию определения, свойственную прилагательному.

2) **А это интересная цитата по теме,** вот **только что** внимательно прочитанная в старом (основательно затрепанном) учебнике.

Из учебника для вузов «Морфология современного русского языка», **2009 год.**

Определение

**Причастие** – гибридная неспрягаемая форма глагола, обладающая признаками прилагательного и глагола и **обозначающая действие как протекающий во времени признак.**

Итак, причастие **обозначает действие как признак.** Получается, что, мое «авторство», увы,  отменяется.

**А как сейчас в школьных учебниках пишут?** Оказывается, по-разному.

**Вот Русский язык (10 - 11 кл), 2007 год**. Здесь причастие "обозначает признак предмета по действию".

А что есть поновее? **Голуб И.Б. ЕГЭ, 2015 год**. "Причастие обозначает действие и указывает на признак".

Сравним с комментарием: *Причастие указывает как на действие, и подобно прилагательному на признак предмета*.

Пожалуй, нет, обозначать и указывать – это **разные вещи**.

И тогда становится интересно: а **в 2020-м году как учат школьников определять причастие?** Вот узнать бы...

Comment: Возьмем причастие _голодающий_. Какое здесь действие ставится на первое место? «Голодать»? Но ведь это не действие, а состояние. Ваше определение, выходит, не универсально.

Comment: 1) И действие, и состояние в общем случае определяются как процессуальный признак, они не противопоставлены друг другу. Термин «состояние» чаще применяется при определении именного сказуемого.2) В существующем определении указано действие, эта формулировка и рассматривается. 3) Речь идет преимущественно о страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени, хотя и других видов тоже касается.

Comment: Нет-нет, подождите. Что такое общий случай? Кем определяются? Так вы пишете не о процессуальности, а о том, что причастие есть в первую очередь действие.

Comment: Я не совсем вас понимаю.  поэтому давайте отвлечемся от комментария, он слишком частного характера, и вернемся к вопросу. Я всего лишь переставляю слова в известном определении. Там написано, что причастие - это  в первую очередь признак, а я думаю, что это в первую очередь действие. И прошу высказаться участников на тему, какое определение они считают более правильным. И это всё, ничего большего.

Comment: А действие по признаку - это как?

Comment: Серж, а «признак по действию» – это как?   Обычно классификация делается по признакам, а здесь  классифицируются сами признаки? Короче говоря, меня  это определение всегда смущало и сейчас не  кажется безупречным.  К тому же я рассматриваю формулировку «действие как признак», то есть действие, представленное в виде признака (в признаковой форме прилагательного). Здесь мне всё понятно. Спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: Sharon, это правильно не ставить "?" во фразе "Но почему..." в начале?

Comment: Артем, я думаю, что вопросительный знак не нужен, так как по Розенталю  он ставится, если все части сложного предложения, входящие в его состав,  или только последняя часть  заключают в себе вопрос. \у меня же последняя часть явно не вопросительная.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, почитал, но такого случая там, к сожалению не разбирается. Если бы я был на вашем месте, то поставил бы вопросительный знак, а последнюю фразу сделал отдельным предложением. Или добавил бы "непонятно": "Но непонятно, почему нельзя сказать так..."

Comment: Артем, Розенталь разобрал СПП, БСП, ССП, но не мог же он разобрать всё.  В то же время он обозначил нечто общее: последнее предложение при постановке знака  обязательно должно быть вопросительным, иначе смысл будет искажен.  Я ведь там не спрашиваю, а утверждаю. А что, кстати,  у нас? А у нас сложное предложение с двумя видами бессоюзной связи. Разделить предложение? Вот этого бы не хотелось, так оно выглядит компактнее. В тексте и так очень много предложений (шутка).

Comment: Обычная формулировка такая. Причастия обозначают признак педмета по действию. Ср.:  Цветущий сад. Цветущий - причастие, указывает на признак предмета по действию. А не наоборот.

Comment: @Артем, Sharon права: вопросительный знак не нужен.

Comment: @Серж  Цветущий сад?  А я думаю. что здесь  причастие указывает на то, что сад  цветет, то есть это действие в форме признака? Вас смущает вопрос "какой"? А вопрос тоже позаимствован у прилагательного (вместе с формой). Теперь он "что делает", а не  "какой". Форма-то прилагательного, а главное содержание действия остается даже в этой форме.

Comment: Я бы даже сказала так: причастие - это  компактная УПАКОВОЧНАЯ ФОРМА для глагола, чтобы его было удобно использовать в различных синтаксических конструкциях. Например: Сад, который цветет, - это цветущий сад.

Comment: @Sharon, но ведь прилагательное не указывает на признак действия.

Comment: Я бы избегал таких фраз. А добавить "непонятно" вам тоже не нравится? Я не прошу тут менять, просто интересно обсудить в целом.

Comment: Серж, к сожалению я не поняла вашей мысли

Comment: Артем, я полагаю, что вопросительный знак отсутствует по правилам. Лишние слова и более сложные конструкции "растягивают"текст,  смысл которого и без них вполне понятен.  Стиль дискуссионный, мысль желательно высказывать  чётко, убеждать читателя. Поэтому информационная нагрузка слов должна быть максимальной.В общем, ради "сомнительного" вопросительного знака я не готова менять предложение.

Comment: Причастие указывает как на действие, и подобно прилагательному на признак предмета.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за комментарии, я вам отвечу в дополнении к вопросу.

Comment: Sharon, ваше дополнение к вопросу прочитал. Сейчас, увы, не могу ответить. Но в ближайшее время отвечу.

Comment: Серж, а может, вы дадите общий ответ, хотя бы краткий, в двух словах. Важна ли формулировка, какая из них правильнее, почему  в современные учебники вносят изменение, да и вносят ли вообще? Стоит ли обращать внимание на эти мелочи или они не мелочи вовсе? Мне очень интересно само отношение к проблеме – тема "внимательного читателя", если ее можно так назвать.

Comment: Sharon, я проконсультировался с лингвистами Омского института, те тоже считают, что причастие обрзначает признак, связанный с действием.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж,так многие раньше считали, судя по  общепринятому во многих учебниках определению. Но в настоящее время это уже не единственная точка зрения.

Comment: Sharon, а что изменилось? К сожалению, у меня нет современных учебников, а интернет-изданием не всегда стоит доверять.

Comment: Казалось бы, формулировка мало что значит: признак как действие или действие как признак. Но с первым вариантом как-то забывается, что причастие - это всё-таки форма глагола, а не наоборот.  Когда люди утверждают, что причастие обозначает качественный признак, который появляется  в ходе действия, приходится задуматься и над формулировкой тоже. Всё-таки причастие обозначает именно действие предмета, хотя при этом использует грамматическую форму прилагательного.

Comment: Возможно и так. Но: цветущий сад- что здесь: признак предмета или же действие предмета как признак?