# Допустимо ли использовать действительное причастие прошедшего времени?

Tags: причастия

> Он сидел в ресторане, не име**ющего** названия.

Допустимо ли использовать "не име**вшего**"? В предложении подразумевается, что у ресторана нет названия, а это значит, что надо использовать действительное причастие настоящего времени ("не имеющего"). Но почему-то эта фраза сильно режет слух.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Режет слух, потому что неверное согласование.
Правильно:
*Он сидел в ресторане, не имеющем названия.

Он сидел в не имеющем названия ресторане.* || Просто для наглядности, такой порядок слов не подходит.
При обособлении причастного оборота согласование не меняется.

Рассмотрим пример, где "он сидит":
*Он сидит в ресторане, не имеющем названия.*
Важно то, что он сейчас не имеет названия, поэтому настоящее время. Если прошедшее, то можно подумать, что когда-то не имел, а сейчас уже всё изменилось — и обычно с такой целью его и употребляют.

Другое дело, если есть слово "никогда":
*Он сидит в ресторане, никогда не имевшем названия.* || Но в плане стилистики желательно переформулировать:
*Он сидит в ресторане, у которого никогда не было названия.*

А раз там "сидел", то прошедшее тоже возможно, потому что у него тогда не было названия, а сейчас уже может быть по-другому.
А с настоящим получается так:
*Он сидел в ресторане, не имеющем [на тот момент] названия.*

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Что же насчёт времён, в чём разница?

У Розенталя есть интересная информация:
При прошедшем времени глагола-сказуемого причастие настоящего времени указывает на постоянный признак, причастие прошедшего времени – на временный признак. Например: *Нас заинтересовал домик, стоящий на опушке леса* (ср.: *...который стоит...*). – *Артем схватил тяжелый молот, стоявший у наковальни...* (Н. Островский) (ср.: *...который стоял...*).
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Если ресторан не имеет названия до сих пор, то это постоянный признак и однозначно требуется настоящее время. Если уже имеет, то признак временный и однозначно прошедшее.

Comment: А как же подстановка для проверки: Он сидел в ресторане, который не имел названия.  Так ведь надо говорить. Сравнить: Он сидел в ресторане, который не имеет названия (это выглядит некорректно)

Comment: Здесь никто не предлагает подстановку. Розенталь предлагает сравнить.

Comment: А я спрашиваю, почему нет соответствия? Вы знаете?

Comment: Вот предложение: Странно, что он так долго оставался спокоен, как будто спорщики говорили о чем-то, не имевшем к нему касательства.[Ю. В. Трифонов. Нетерпение (1973)] Почему здесь прошедшее время (не имевшем)?

Comment: *почему нет соответствия?* — потому что придаточные имеют временную привязку, в отличие от причастных оборотов. *Почему здесь прошедшее время (не имевшем)?* — может, временный признак (не имело, а потом может оказаться, что имеет).

Comment: @JimKorbett Розенталь говорит о признаке, "размахивающий" — это больше действие, чем признак.

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понимаю про признак. Дело в том, что прошедшее или настоящее причастие определяется положением этого в настоящем. Например: ‟Мы пошли в бар, находящийся в конце улицы”. (В настоящем он всё ещё находится там же). Мы пошли в бар, находившийся в конце улицы. (Его там сейчас уже нет.) А если действие короткое, то используется настоящее причастие — ‟Мы увидели человека, размахивающего битой”, ‟Мы встретили человека, выгуливающего собаку”.

Comment: Просто я по примерам и словам в скобках подумал, что Розенталь именно это и написал.

Comment: @JimKorbett У причастия либо действие на первом плане ("что делающий?" больше подходит), либо признак ("какой?" лучше отражает суть). Первые: *размахивающий, горящий, играющий, танцующий*. Вторые: *находящийся, имеющий, знающий, понимающий*. Сейчас смотрю, что, когда короткое, прошедшее тоже возможно, просто настоящее лучше.

Comment: @Sharon Ваш пример корректен в плане грамматики: *Он сидел в ресторане, который [сейчас] не имеет названия.* См. мой ответ: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471755

Comment: При чём здесь вообще причастие. Все причастия это характеристика по действию. Вторые - то, что в английском называется глаголами состояния или положения, то есть когда кто-то не выполняет некое действие, а пребывает в положении. При чём здесь вообще слово признак, при чём здесь вообще причастия? Это пример ужасающе отвратительной формулировки.

Comment: @JimKorbett У причастий либо прилагательность доминирует, либо глагольность. Но дело не только в этом. Вы читали, что Розенталь до этого говорит? Там, где про детей. Не очень это понял. Но вот тот пример сопоставим с вашими. Когда действие не может продолжаться вечно, ситуация другая.

Comment: То что у причастий что-то там доминирует - это какие-то субъективные аморфные соображения. Я не вижу, почему если, например, есть глагол положения ‟находится”, то в причастии от него будет больше ‟прилагательности”, чем ‟глагольности”.

Comment: @JimKorbett Нет, это важно, потому что оно сказывается на написании НЕ с причастиями. Вы у других спросите. Это обычно обсуждают, когда причастие в прошедшем. Уже много раз было, вы где-то бродили и не видели.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном примере использование причастия **«не имевшего»**  допускается и, как я думаю, является **более обоснованным:**

*Он сидел в ресторане, **не имевшем названия**.*

**Пояснение**

**Теория**

**1. Розенталь §211. Причастные обороты** http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Значение времени в причастии **относительное**: в одних случаях наблюдается **соотносительность времен**, выраженных причастием и глаголом-сказуемым, например: *видел детей, **играющих на бульваре*** (видел в то время, когда они играли); в других случаях время, выраженное причастием, соотносится **с моментом речи**, предшествует ему, например: *видел детей, **игравших на бульваре.***

При прошедшем времени глагола-сказуемого причастие настоящего времени указывает **на постоянный признак**, причастие прошедшего времени – на **временный признак**.

**2. Информация у Розенталя не кажется вполне ясной**, хотя он указывает на **три признака для различения этих форм**: (1) соотнесённость с моментом речи или соответствие времен глагола и деепричастия; (2) постоянный или временный признак; (3) замена причастного оборота определительным придаточным.

3. Рассмотрим **частный случай,** когда сказуемое  выражено глаголом **несовершенного вида в форме прошедшего времени,** а деепричастие также образовано от глагола **несовершенного вида**.

В этом случае возникает интересная ситуация: в предложении можно использовать **две формы действительного причастия** (настоящего и прошедшего времени), причем кажется, что на слух они подходят обе: *видел детей, **играющих/игравших**  на бульваре.* Конечно, важен **контекст**, который проясняет ситуацию, тогда пользователю легче ориентироваться при выборе форм.

Исходя из практических примеров в Накорпусе, можно ориентироваться  на следующую закономерность эмпирического характера.  Причастие ***играющий*** подчёркивает то, что действие происходит **в текущий момент** прошлого, а причастие ***игравших***  просто **относит действие** сказуемого и причастия к **прошлому,** ничего не подчеркивая.

Например: *Он видел детей, **играющих** на бульваре, и они напомнили ему его собственное детство.* – *Он видел детей, **игравших** на бульваре, фонтан, клумбы с яркими цветами – всё вокруг радовалось  приходу весеннего тепла.*

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

**(1) Текущий момент речи подчеркивается:**

Мы **говорим** о подростке, ещё **не имеющем** своего жизненного опыта. [Наши дети: Подростки (2004)]

Она смотрела на меня недоуменно, точно я **говорю** о чем-то отношения к ней **не имеющем**, вроде движения планет. [Н. В. Нестерова. Грезиетка (2013)]

Он силился вспомнить подробности прошедшей ночи, касающиеся лично его, но при этом **думал** о себе в третьем лице, как бы о некоем литературном герое, конкретно **не имеющем** к нему никакого отношения. [Виктор Слипенчук. Зинзивер (2001)]

**(2) Обозначена соотнесенность прошедшего времени для сказуемого и деепричастия**

В этих выступлениях итальянская балерина **появлялась** в небольшом и довольно скромном танце, **не имевшем** отношения к сюжету оперетки. [А. Н. Бенуа. Жизнь художника (1955)]

Так, Свидерский **настаивал** на заказе какой-то весьма подозрительной фирме в Бордо ― городе, **не имевшем** ничего общего с военной промышленностью. [А. А. Игнатьев. Пятьдесят лет в строю. Кн. 4 (1947-1953)]

Проходившие мимо люди, никакого отношения к свадьбе **не имевшие**, тоже почему-то **кричали** «ура!» [Алексей Грачев. Ярый против видеопиратов (1999)]

А как **работали** старые врачи, **не имевшие** фактически никаких лекарств? [Михаил Чулаки. Прощай, зеленая Пряжка (1998)]

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Я не брал во внимание соотношение времени еще и для сказуемого.

Comment: Здесь совсем не такая ситуация! Ясно, что дети не могут играть до сих пор. Здесь же ресторан может не иметь названия до сих пор, а "не имевший" звучит так, что у него уже есть название. Чья это вина? Розенталя. Он очень мало написал.

Comment: *это больше похоже на постоянный признак* — "постоянный признак" у Розенталя не о том, там имеется в виду, что действие продолжается до сих пор, это никак не то, что раз дети играли, то они всегда остаются игравшими.

Comment: *В ваших ответах как обычно: анализ, философия, и при этом никаких практических рекомендаций и ни одного примера из литературы. Как говорится, прочитать и забыть, ничему НЕ НАУЧИШБСЯ* — вот будете сами отвечать. У меня есть рекомендации, у вас же они размазаны, будто их и нет.

Comment: Вы не понимаете главного: этот пример не такой, как пример про детей. А как можно доверять тем примерам из Нацкорпуса, тогда как там куча ошибок? А где есть только классика, не знаю. Анализ — это самое ценное. Интересует или нет, но прошедшее позволяет понять, что ситуация изменилась. **А в примере Розенталя напишете "стоявший"?** Никого же не интересует, что с тем домом сейчас. А у меня в ответе не так написано (процесс — в тот момент и факт — соотнесённость с прошлым)? Что вы нового добавили?

Comment: Да пожалуйста, на здоровье, думайте как вам хочется. Ваш же ответ принят, что вам беспокоиться. Я высказала свое мнение, может, кому будет интересно, как быстро решить задачу безо всякой философии. А чем вам домик не угодил? "Нас заинтересовал домик, стоящий на опушке леса". Здесь можно написать «стоявший», то есть обозначить только отнесенность действия к прошлому, смысл сказанного от этого НЕ ИЗМЕНИТСЯ, никто и не заметит замену.  Но автор обозначил присутствие домика в текущий момент. Это его авторское право.  А примеры из корпуса взяты из  литературы, это не самиздат, корректоры проверяли.

Comment: А вот такую задачу вы можете решить? Придумайте текст про детей, игравших/играющих на бульваре. Чтобы было видно семантику двух вариантов, когда какой использовать. Вообразите себя писателем. У меня в ответе есть парные варианты.

Comment: То есть вы игнорируете то, что написал Розенталь о домике? Мы должны верить вам, а не ему? Так? **Когда признак может быть постоянным (в прямом смысле этого слова), совсем другая история.** Розенталь виноват в том, что не сказал этого.

Comment: *что вам беспокоиться* — я беспокоюсь, когда кто-то говорит неверное. Но сейчас вы не против меня, а против Розенталя. Своё мнение не высказывайте, отвечайте тогда, когда уверены на 100%, когда готовы поспорить на что-то ценное. Тогда будет высокая вероятность того, что вы правы. Во всяком случае, я так делаю. Если не можете быть на 100% уверенной, то учитесь, тренируйте ум.

Comment: Ладно, закрыли тему.  В наставлениях я не особо нуждаюсь. Давайте я буду тренировать ум,  а вы свои теории проверяйте практикой и давайте четкие и ясные рекомендации, как решить задачу. Пока я не вижу этого в ваших ответах. На том и закончим разговор.

Comment: Подскажите, на каком сайте только примеры из классики? А то в Нацкорпусе много ошибок. Но туда заглядываю, когда нужны примеры, чтобы разобраться. Но стилистику обычно можно понять и без него. Вы же не анализируете каждый пример, тогда зачем они? И так понятно, что пишут по-разному. Смысл в ваших примерах? Человек может зайти в Нацкорпус и прочитать. Смысл есть, если вы анализируете примеры по отдельности. Но вы же этого никогда не делали. Моя рекомендация не очень отличается от вашей, не понимаю, что вас не устраивает. Цитируйте ответ и комментируйте, тогда ваша критика будет конструктивной.

Comment: *Моя рекомендация не очень отличается от вашей* — но они не для примера из вопроса, потому что там действие может продолжаться очень долго, и из-за этого надо ориентироваться по другому принципу, о котором говорит Розенталь. Они для коротких действий (*играющие дети, воющий волк*).

Comment: Вы считаете мой ответ неверным. Он в какой-то мере действительно носит эмпирический (упрощенный) характер и обобщает  практический материал. Но ваш ответ с серьезной наукой тоже имеет мало чего общего. РОЗЕНТАЛЬ также в  научную трактовку не особо углубляется, поэтому и текст у него не совсем ясный. Давайте так. Я могу убрать свой ответ вообще, если вы проработаете грамматический материал по этой теме, которая называется так: 3.3. Выбор между действительными причастиями прошедшего и настоящего времени В ПОЗИЦИИ КОНКУРЕНЦИИ.

Comment: Ну и представите нам краткий, но понятный конспект. Я просмотрела этот материал и решила, что он довольно сложен, поэтому мне не захотелось тратить время на его изучение. Там теория перемешана со статистикой, рассмотрено влияние большого количества факторов, и я не уверена, что можно на этой основе составить практическое руководство для пользователей. А это адрес:  http://rusgram.ru/Действительное_причастие#33

Comment: Ваша ошибка только в том, что вы предлагаете применить это к примеру из вопроса. Пытался это сделать, но возникает стойкое ощущение, что хотят сообщить за счёт прошедшего, что у ресторана не было названия, а теперь уже есть. В этом случае действует то, что у Розенталя во втором абзаце. Не понимаю информацию по ссылке, потому что там куча терминов. Если вы бы "перевели" и запостили, то было бы очень полезно и круто.

Comment: Но некоторые примеры интересны. Плохо то, что они в основном говорят про случаи, когда корректен только один вариант (и без них легко определить какой). Нас же интересует, как выбрать, если оба варианта возможны. Хотя не думаю, что есть что-то ещё, кроме того, о чём мы сказали (это касается действий, которые не могут продолжаться очень долго).

Comment: Ладно, приятного прочтения. Составите краткую и понятную  "инструкцию" для пользователей, решите с ее помощью задачу  для заданного вопроса – тогда и поговорим. Обсуждать с вами частные детали я не буду.

Comment: Но вы же по части терминов. Это же родной для вас язык. Мне там сложно понять, в основном анализирую примеры.

Comment: Розенталь за это дело не взялся,  так и я не буду.  Я прото хотела вам сказать, что наука проблемой занимается,  но практического руководства никто составить не спешит.

Comment: @Sharon *В приведенном примере использование причастия «не имевшего» допускается...* Надо, наверно, "не имевшем".

Comment: Данная задача решается по принципу Розенталя (он во втором моём ответе). А вот пример про детей и подобные надо.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Нет, надо "не имевший", поскольку есть родовое слово.

Comment: @oleedd Э-э-э... Не поняла... Он сидел в ресторане, не имевший названия?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Нет, имею в виду исключительно первое предложение ответа. Пример: *Использование существительного "ресторан"* (не "ресторане", хоть в примере так и написано).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Использование слова в падеже не грамотно, когда есть родовое слово. Если хотим написать в падеже, то родовое слово надо убрать: *В приведенном примере использование «не имевшем» допускается...* Да и если строго, то это не причастие, а причастие с отрицанием. Такую строгость надо соблюдать, если пишете диссертацию, статью или т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Режет слух потому, что ‟ресторане” — предложный падеж, то есть и причастие нужно ставить в предложный — ‟Он сидел в ресторане, не имеющем названия”.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш случай подходит под это правило Розенталя, но что происходит, когда не длительный признак, а короткое действие?

В таких случаях очень тонкая разница:
*Он видел волка, воющего на луну.* || Здесь подчёркивается процесс, что он в тот момент был воющим.
*Он видел волка, вывшего на луну.* || Здесь просто сообщается о факте, что волк тогда выл.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Любое несовершённое причастие обозначает характеристику по действию, которое происходило одновременно со сказуемым. Не надо использовать слово ‟признак”: ‟признак” в этом значении это то же, что и характеристика, то есть быстрый, красный, синий и т. д. Лучше  используйте сочетания ‟статичный глагол” или ‟глагол пребывания в положении”.

Comment: Слово "признак" использует Розенталь. Если вы хотите обсудить это, то вам сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460910

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение.